# Replacing data from a list with its position

Tags: c#, list, listbox

I have made some code that allows the user to enter a sentence into a richtextbox, and then the data will be saved into a list and have the duplicates removed.

What I want to know is how I would make the overwrite the words in the list with their positions, and then replace the positions of the original sentence with those positions.

E.g: in the sentence `Hello this is a test I hope this test works` the sentence will be saved, removed of duplicates, and output `hello, this, is, a, test, I, hope, works`, the code replaces this with `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8` (I think).

Now I need to make the program replace the actual words in the list with its position in the original so it will finally say `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 2 5 8` separated by commas.

This is my code:

```
string sentence = richTextBox1.Text;

list = sentence.Split(delimiterChars).ToList();
listoriginal = sentence.Split(delimiterChars).ToList();
listBox1.Items.Add("Full sentence: " + String.Join(" ", list));
list = list.Distinct(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase).ToList();
listBox1.Items.Add("Words in the input: " + String.Join(", ", list));

for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    list[i] = list[i].ToString();
    listoriginal[i] = listoriginal[i].ToString();
    resultList = listoriginal.Select(x => x.Replace(listoriginal[i], list[i])).ToList();
    i++;
}

listBox1.Items.Add("Final result: " + String.Join(", ", resultList));
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably to use a key/value store like a dictionary - once you have eliminated the duplicates you can push the key/values into the dictionary and use that to re-build the sentence.

```
// Create dictionary
var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();

// When looping through the words to determine index add each word to the dict - the word being the key and the value being the index
dict.Add(word, index);
```

Then

```
foreach(var word in words) {
    // Get the value from the dictionary for the associated key (the key being the word)
    var index = dict[word];
    // do stuff with index
}
```

You can use string concatenation to re-build the string rather than replace (since you are indexing all words).

Common advice will be to use `StringBuilder` when you are concerned about performance/memory since strings are immutable

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach(var word in words) {
    sb.Append(dict[word]);
    sb.Append(" ");
}

sb.ToString();
```

Edit:

Here's a more full example...

```
var sentence = "hello world this is a test hello world";

var words = sentence.Split(' ');
var distinctWords = words.Distinct(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
var ix = 0;
foreach (var word in distinctWords)
{
    dict.Add(word.ToLower(), ix++);
}

var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var word in words)
{
    sb.Append(dict[word.ToLower()]);
    sb.Append(" ");
}

// sb.ToString(); 
// 0 1 2 3 4 5 0 1
```

Obviously since I'm not doing a replace, this may affect the formatting of the original string but it gives you an idea. You can use replace but it will be a lot slower - but it depends on the length of string and how much processing you are doing.

Comment: I am trying to use your solution, but how would I get word and index, would word be list[i] or am I wrong, as for index, I'm just not sure about what that is

Comment: when you pull a distinct list of words using the distinct extension method, loop over them and push each one into the dictionary with an incrementing counter (starting from 0). That's your keyed list that you can use to build the sentence etc.

Answer (score 0):

Create a dictionary with the words that have already been addressed.  Meaning that you would have the following:

```
Dictionary<int, string> words = new Dictionary<int, string>();
words.Items.Add(//number, //word);
```

(Hello, 1)
(this, 2)
(is, 3)
(a, 4)
.....and so on

You can then write a a method that will search to see if a word is already stored, for example:

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<int, string> set in words)
{
    if(set.value == //whatever word is next)
    {
        //write the number in the dictionary here
        //the corresponding number can be grabbed using: set.key
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to populate on the fly a `Dictionary<string, int>` holding the result position of the word. The result words then can be obtained from `Keys` property:

```
var originalWords = sentence.Split(delimiterChars, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var uniqueWordPositions = new Dictionary<string, int>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
var originalWordPositions = new List<int>();
foreach (var word in originalWords)
{
    int position;
    if (!uniqueWordPositions.TryGetValue(word, out position))
        uniqueWordPositions.Add(word, position = uniqueWordPositions.Count + 1);
    originalWordPositions.Add(position);
};
listBox1.Items.Add("Full sentence: " + string.Join(" ", originalWords));
listBox1.Items.Add("Words in the input: " + string.Join(", ", uniqueWordPositions.Keys));
listBox1.Items.Add("Final result: " + string.Join(", ", originalWordPositions));
```